# Uncaught TypeError in Chrome and Safari when referencing the name of a dropdown in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code only seems to work in IE. In Chrome or Safari, I get the following error:

The console error I get in Chrome is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'choosetext' of object # is not a function

Here's the code:

```
function LoadPageText(){
document.location.href = "editpage.asp?file="+document.form.file.value+"&text="+document.form['choosetext'](document.form['choosetext'].selectedIndex).value;
}
```

How do I resolve this error for Safari and Chrome?

Comment: is it showing any issues in any browsers,if so wat?

Comment: try using $('#dropdown_id').val()

Comment: @jade Yes: "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'choosetext' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing values using element id

```
document.getElementById('ElementId').value
```

For drop down list

```
document.getElementById('dropdownId').selectedIndex
```

to get selected index

Comment: Nevermind that, i had a space in the id tag of the dropdown, it works now, thanx for the help!